# How to burn text to each video frame while muxing or after encoding in android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to burn text to each frame while muxing in android. Currently I am able to encode an mp4 video file from an array of NalUnits where each unit is a frame represented by byte[] that is saved from an rtp packet from an rtsp stream. During the muxing process I want to burn a timestamp text to each frame. Can it be done using android without using ffmpeg? If not, how can I achieve this using ffmpeg? Because I can save the timestamp to a file and later after the video is encoded can burn the timestamp to each frame.

This is how I am currently muxing each frame so ideally before writing the data I want to burng the timestamp to the frame:

```
private void muxFrame(FrameQueue.Frame frame, int encodeIndex, boolean isVideoEOS) {
    long presentationTimeUs = computePresentationTimeNsec(encodeIndex);

    int inputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
        inputBuffer.put(frame.getData());


        codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, frame.getOffset(), frame.getLength(), frame.getTimestamp(), 0);
    }

    // Create a MediaCodec.BufferInfo to hold the frame information
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo muxerOutputBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();

    int outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(muxerOutputBufferInfo, 1000);

    switch (outputBufferIndex) {
        case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
            MediaFormat newFormat = codec.getOutputFormat();
            mVideoTrack = muxer.addTrack(newFormat);
            muxer.start();
            break;
        case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
            break;
        default:
            // Set the size, presentation time, and flags of the muxerOutputBufferInfo

            muxerOutputBufferInfo.size = frame.getLength();
            muxerOutputBufferInfo.offset = 0;
            muxerOutputBufferInfo.flags = isVideoEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME;
            muxerOutputBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = presentationTimeUs;
            // Write the frame data to the muxer
            muxer.writeSampleData(mVideoTrack, ByteBuffer.wrap(frame.getData()), muxerOutputBufferInfo);
            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"During the muxing process I want to burn a timestamp text to each frame"_ You have to: **(1)** First decode each frame (YUV data) into a Bitmap (RGB data), **(2)** Then you can add text to the bitmap itself, **(3)** Then re-encode bitmap as a new H264 frame, **(4)** Finally mux the new H264 frame into the MP4. **PS:** You need to expand your question to get help on the part of that process that you're stuck with...

Comment: PS: Remember there is a grace period of an "extra 24 hours" for Bounties with no accepted Answer when the deadline comes. If the bounty ends, don't worry since an Answer might be on the way from another reader.